# JavaScript indexOf from end of search string

Tags: javascript

Javascript's `String.indexOf` returns the index of the a search term within a string.

It returns the index of where the string is first found, from the beginning of the search string. example:

```
'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.indexOf('def') = 3;
```

But I need to get it from the end of the search, for example:

```
'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.indexOf('def') = 6; //essentially index + searchString.length
```

so that I can then `String.substr` from the returned value to get the string after that point.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I sorted this with a simple function, but after writing it, I just thought it was that simple, and useful that i couldnt understand why it wasn't already implemented into JavaScript!?

```
String.prototype.indexOfEnd = function(string) {
    var io = this.indexOf(string);
    return io == -1 ? -1 : io + string.length;
}
```

which will have the desired result

```
'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.indexOfEnd('def'); //6
```

EDIT might aswell include the lastIndexOf implementation too

```
String.prototype.lastIndexOfEnd = function(string) {
    var io = this.lastIndexOf(string);
    return io == -1 ? -1 : io + string.length;
}
```

Comment: it's not a standard function precisely because it _is_ so trivial!  I've never seen such a function in _any_ computer language's standard string handling library.

Comment: That's a fair point. But I think it's a useful extension of String. For my currect project atleast anyway! :)

Comment: @Alnitak It's useful if you're parsing strings.

Answer (score 1):

```
var findStr = "def";
var searchString = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
var endOf = -1;
endOf = searchString.lastIndexOf(findStr) > 0 ? searchString.lastIndexOf(findStr) + findStr.length : endOf;
alert(endOf);
```

Alerts -1 if not found

Note returns 23 if you have this string:

```
var searchString = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstdefuvwxyz';
```

As a function:

```
function endofstring (searchStr,findStr){
    return searchStr.lastIndexOf(findStr) > 0 ? searchStr.lastIndexOf(findStr) + findStr.length : -1;
}

endofstring(searchString,"def");
```

Comment: I think my original suggestion is neater.

Comment: @RoryPicko92 - one alternative, this one does not pollute the string prototype.  Up to the OP which works for them.

Comment: Why is using the String prototype a bad thing, I think its neater than having stray functions. Also I was mainly refering to you calling `lastIndexOf` twice.

Comment: Fair point the double call, does avoid the interim `var` declaration, only reason I did it that way, as I said, alternatives but neither is incorrect.