# How to get index of letter in a string from end to begin?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can check that a string includes letter with using of .indexOf():

```
my_string = 'sdf sdfdsf dfdsdfs';
console.log(my_string.indexOf(' '));
// returns 4
```

Is exists method to do the same but from end to begin? (example above must returns 11 - the first white space from right to left)

Comment: @James Nope, different questions.

Comment: `console.log(my_string.indexOf(' '));` returns 3 with your input, not 4. I don't know how you're expecting "11"; the first white space from right to left is in the 9th position?

Comment: @user3775292, First white space from right to left is the 11th position from l to r and is index 10 from l to r

Comment: If you're expecting 11 (actually, 10) then you're counting from left to right, not right to left as you state. Therefore the answers featuring `lastIndexOf()` will work for you. If you *don't* mean that, then @Savv's answer will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `lastIndexOf`.

```
my_string = 'sdf sdfdsf dfdsdfs';
console.log(my_string.lastIndexOf(' '));
```

Comment: Why the best answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18893402/javascript-indexof-from-end-of-search-string is define new method if lastIndexOf is exists?

Comment: That's a different usage, there they want to get the index of the end of the search, as opposed to the beginning.

Comment: Thanks for help, Scimonster.

Answer (score 2):

Reverse your string and perform `indexOf()`:

```
reverseString = my_string.split("").reverse().join("");
console.log(my_string.length - reverseString.indexOf(' '));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
console.log(my_string.lastIndexOf(" "));
```