# Text color change with search input but not work as expected

Tags: javascript, html

I have tried help from :
[How to highlight text using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8644428/how-to-highlight-text-using-javascript) - Stackoverflow link
[How do I get the starting and ending index of a highlighted piece of a string in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57931853) - Stackoverflow link
[A one-line solution to highlighting search matches](https://bitsofco.de/a-one-line-solution-to-highlighting-search-matches/) - Outside link

But reached upto a certain mark of achievement.

Now only first letters are highlighted . Also they get lowercase if I enter a lowercase letter in search and vice-versa
When the input is cleared , than the whole `replace` is shown including `tag` names

Here is what I reached upto :

```js
function refree() {
  var reed = document.getElementById("search").value;
  var reed1 = reed.toLowerCase();
  var reader = document.getElementsByClassName("deviceNameCardHead")

  // for (let i = 0; i < reader.length; i++) {
  reader[0].innerHTML = reader[0].innerHTML.replace(new RegExp(reed1, 'gi'), `<span class="highlight">${reed}</span>`);
}
//}
```

```css
.highlight {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="devicesBtnData">
  <div class="searchDevice">
    <span class="searchDeviceBtn">Search Device</span>
    <input id="search" type="search" placeholder="Try it" oninput="refree()">
    <br>
  </div>

  <div class="deviceNameCard">
    <h3 class="deviceNameCardHead">Lenova Yoga laptop Pro</h3>
  </div>

</div>
```

Below answer solved most of the problems . But can there be a way such that :

- User enter `p` in `input` than all occurrences of `p` are highlighted whether it is lowercase or uppercase without changing its all occurrences to lowercase if `p` entered is in lowercase like this : Lenova Yoga la**p**to**p** **p**ro
  but should be like this
  Lenova Yoga la**p**to**p** **P**ro (when `p` is either lowercase or uppercase)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex isn't working if there is a `span` tag between the letters. Therefor you could replace `reader[0].innerHTML` with `reader[0].textContent`. This also solves the issue when the input is cleared.

By the way: if you use `document.querySelector(...)` you can omit the `[0]` in `reader[0]` because it only selects the first element with that selector.

**Working example:** (*simple for demonstration*)

```js
function refree() {
  var reed = document.getElementById("search").value;
  var reed1 = reed.toLowerCase();
  var reader = document.querySelector(".deviceNameCardHead");

  reader.innerHTML = reader.textContent.replace(new RegExp(reed1, 'gi'), `<span class="highlight">${reed}</span>`);
}
```

```css
.highlight {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="devicesBtnData">
  <div class="searchDevice">
    <span class="searchDeviceBtn">Search Device</span>
    <input id="search" type="search" placeholder="Try it" oninput="refree()">
  </div>

  <div class="deviceNameCard">
    <h3 class="deviceNameCardHead">Lenova Yoga laptop Pro</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

To solve the issue that it changes the case of the yellow letters you need a bit more code.

First you have to store the string from `.deviceNameCardHead` in a variable (for example `reader_text`), convert it to lower case for a case insensitive search and store that also in a variable (for example `lower_text`):

```js
const reader_text = reader.textContent;
const lower_text = reader_text.toLowerCase();
```

Then you have to loop over all chars of `reader_text` to find all occurrences of the search string and store all index values in an array (for example `index_array`):

```js
for(i = 0; i < lower_text.length; i++) {
  const reed_index = lower_text.indexOf(reed1, i);
    
  if(reed_index >= 0) {
    index_array.push(reed_index);
  }
}
```

Then you have to loop over the `index_array` and store all occurrences from the original string in an array (for example `highlight_array`) to obtain lower and upper case letters. To minimize an array to unique values you can use the `Set()` constructor and spread syntax `[...]`.

```js
index_array = [...new Set(index_array)];
index_array.forEach(function(val) {
  highlight_array.push(reader_text.substr(val, reed.length));
});
```

After that you have to loop over the `highlight_array` and replace all upper and lower case occurrences separately with `span.highlight`-wrapped values. To prevent the overwriting of `reader_text` use a separate variable (for example `highlight_text`):

```js
let highlight_text = reader_text;

highlight_array = [...new Set(highlight_array)];
highlight_array.forEach(function(val) {
  highlight_text = highlight_text.replaceAll(val, `<span class="highlight">${val}</span>`);
});
```

And finally you have to replace the string from `.deviceNameCardHead` with `highlight_text`:

```js
reader.innerHTML = highlight_text;
```

**Working example:**

```js
const reader = document.querySelector(".deviceNameCardHead");
const reader_text = reader.textContent;
const lower_text = reader_text.toLowerCase();

function refree() {
  const reed = document.getElementById("search").value;
  const reed1 = reed.toLowerCase();
  let highlight_text = reader_text;
  let highlight_array = [];
  let index_array = [];
  
  for(i = 0; i < lower_text.length; i++) {
    const reed_index = lower_text.indexOf(reed1, i);
    
    if(reed_index >= 0) {
      index_array.push(reed_index);
    }
  }

  index_array = [...new Set(index_array)];
  index_array.forEach(function(val) {
    highlight_array.push(reader_text.substr(val, reed.length));
  });

  highlight_array = [...new Set(highlight_array)];
  highlight_array.forEach(function(val) {
    highlight_text = highlight_text.replaceAll(val, `<span class="highlight">${val}</span>`);
  });
  
  reader.innerHTML = highlight_text;
}
```

```css
.highlight {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="devicesBtnData">
  <div class="searchDevice">
    <span class="searchDeviceBtn">Search Device</span>
    <input id="search" type="search" placeholder="Try it" oninput="refree()">
  </div>

  <div class="deviceNameCard">
    <h3 class="deviceNameCardHead">Lenova Yoga press laptop Pro</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot . Can it be like this : if I search for `p` then all `p` are highlighted irrespective of there being lowercase or uppercase . And **p** in text don't change to lowercase or uppercase as of the search

Comment: Still changing all occurrence of `p` to case in which it is entered like : Lenova Yoga la**p**to**p** **p**ro  . If `p` is entered in lowercase

Comment: Also Lenova Yoga la**P**to**P** **P**ro  . If `p` is entered in uppercase

Comment: Can  it be like this : Lenova Yoga la**p**to**p** **P**ro  . Either `p` is entered in lowercase or uppercase

Comment: Sorry, couldn't use a computer for the last hours. Give me some time...

Comment: No worries @biberman . It is nice of you for solving my problem . If get to a result plz post the answer plz

Comment: When you enter `.` or stuff like `.*` you got some funky stuff going on. There's much more into RegExp than *"just use RegExp"* :)

Comment: @biberman thanks brother for your time and effort

Comment: @biberman I get the answer from your code and some other . Thanks a lot . I used `match` method in the 3rd link of question . A one line solution one

Comment: @biberman I have posted the answer you can check it but if you can tell the use of `match` in it , will be very helpful

Answer (score 1):

This can be the solution . But I don't know how `match` used here . It is my first time use of it . If anyone can tell about it in comments will be helpful

```js
const reader = document.querySelector(".deviceNameCardHead");
const reader_text = reader.textContent;

function refree() {
  var reed = document.getElementById("search").value;
  var reed1 = reed.toLowerCase();

  // for (let i = 0; i < reader.length; i++) {
  reader.innerHTML = reader_text.replace(new RegExp(reed1, 'gi'), (match) => `<span class="highlight">${match}</span>`);
}
//}
```

```css
.highlight {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="devicesBtnData">
  <div class="searchDevice">
    <span class="searchDeviceBtn">Search Device</span>
    <input id="search" type="search" placeholder="Try it" oninput="refree()">
    <br>
  </div>

  <div class="deviceNameCard">
    <h3 class="deviceNameCardHead">Lenova Yoga laptop Pro</h3>
  </div>

</div>
```